# c# вызывать функцию каждые Х миллисекунд

Tags: c#, com-порт, com-port

Как посылать определенную информацию с заданным интервалом устройству, подключенному по COM-порту?

Использовал `Timers.Timer`, `Timer.Elapsed+=Method`...

Проблема в том, что при установке, например, 20ms, вызывается примерно 30-32 функции в секунде, когда по логике должно совершаться 50 вызовов/сек.

Код:

```
Timer = new Timer(frequencyOfCalling);
Timer.Elapsed += SendDataMethod;
Timer.AutoReset = true;
Timer.Enabled = true;
```

Для моей задачи требуется вызывать функцию с частотой 50Гц.
Может быть, кто-нибудь посоветует что-нибудь? Читал, что можно использовать `nanosleep` в C++, но очень хочется вставки эти делать.

[image: Скриншот:]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

20ms - это уже близко к кванту времени Windows, такой интервал выдерживать точно довольно сложно.

Можете попробовать следующие методы:

1. Вынесите таймер из потока GUI в отдельный фоновой поток: создайте отдельный поток и там в цикле делайте `Thread.Sleep`. Ну, или используйте [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Это уже само по себе должно дать прирост точности.
2. Используйте динамическую задержку: вычисляйте сколько времени осталось до следующего события и спите заданное время. Если времени осталось меньше 10мс - не спите вообще. Измеряйте время с помощью Stopwatch - потому что DateTime.Now и Environment.TickCount имеют довольно крупную для вас погрешность (порядка 10мс).

Если ваша цель - просто чтобы было 50 вызовов в секунду - то этих двух пунктов хватит.

3. Поставьте повышенный либо высокий приоритет фоновому потоку или даже приоритет реального времени (нужны будут права админа). Осторожнее с последним: поток реального времени может повесить всю систему, если будет есть слишком много процессорного времени.
4. Откажитесь от Thread.Sleep и используйте вместо него активное ожидание. Не комбинируйте этот метод с приоритетом реального времени на одноядерных системах!
5. Можно попробовать поиграться с параметром [HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\PriorityControl\Win32PrioritySeparation](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc976120).

---

PS что за оборудование-то? Там никак нельзя вызывать его реже?

Comment: Приоритет реального времени разве возможен на чистой винде?

Comment: @Qwertiy реальное время - невозможно. Приоритет реального времени - возможен :)

Comment: @Qwertiy это название такое просто. По факту - наименьший из "ядерного" диапазона приоритетов.

Comment: Вроде реальное время возможно в какой-то расширенной версии винды?

Comment: Решил использовать `CreateTimerQueueTimer`, сделаю вставку C++, думаю будет нормально, ибо с ним получается примерно 49,87 вызовов/секунду

Comment: @Qwertiy честно - не знаю

Comment: @xitryuga я бы вам тогда посоветовал глянуть на класс [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - это, по-идее, обертка над `CreateTimerQueueTimer`

Comment: @xitryuga, можно же и без вставки?

Comment: @xitryuga, ничего Вам не даст вызовы каждые 20ms без дополнительного кода, ни C++, ни что либо другое. Я когда-то RTP генератор писал, там как раз нужно было каждые 20 ms посылать пакеты, так вот, этого реально добиться лишь постоянной корректировкой временного интервала.